# create .jar from Activities

Tags: android

Doe anyone know how to create a .jar file from one activity? 
I don´t need anything else, just to create a .jar from the Activity class itself (I don't need the .xml file).

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Android project which contains a class like:

```
public class ClassA extends Activity {
...
}
```

Be sure to create ONLY a class, no Android Activity. Then you can export a jar file of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use plain export menu to do this. In Eclipse it can be done by `Right button click on project->Export->Java->JAR file` and select only your Activity's file.

Answer (score 1):

You can `export` your class.In eclipse

select your class,do write click on it
export --> java --> jar file